# Is there any better option for accessing both PUT and POST request method in the same API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am calling REST API to add the content on the web page through `POST` request and for modification `put`.  I have `add()` and `save()` button for uploading the content and saving it. I am calling `save()` button for both the request method. But the part is , When ever I want to access the information, I should stop one or other request and perform the action. I thought to make use of **ID** , but I din't got any better idea

Html :

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addmode(cts.information)"> Add </button> 
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="saveinfo()"> Save </button>
```

Angular js :

```
$scope.addmode = function(information) {
    var postinfo = information;
    $http({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/contacts' , 
        method : 'POST',
        data : postinfo
    })
    .then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.selectedcontact = '';
            console.log(response.data)
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Error : " + response.data);
        });    
    };
```

Comment: Show the `saveinfo()` function.

Comment: Wild guess, I think it should be `ng-click="saveinfo(cts.information)"`

Comment: I have used `PUT` request for `saveinfo()` button. I am using same button for both the request @ jjj

Comment: If i use `ng-click="saveinfo(cts.information)"` . It will give error saying information is undefined @ Satpal

Comment: You still need to show the function, and the line that throws the error. We can't know why something is undefined if you don't show the context.

Comment: @ JJJ i have updated the `save()` functionality

Comment: You don't explain your problem well. What says "information is undefined". Not clear.

Comment: take information variable as a scope variable and declare it  ex 


$scope.addmode = function(information) {
    var postinfo = information;  //instead of this  try  $scope.information=information
} 

and in save () pass $scope.information in data

Comment: problem definition is completely unclear, the provided code is just logging the request output, we don't know the login inside saveInfo, I guess you already edited the code snippet you provided but there are a lot of missing logic, try to update your issue description

Comment: The code which i posted is exactly correct. I should write separate function for `addmode()`and `save()` Button. In `save()` button , i should pass the **URL**. @ Mohamed Gaber